# if else statement, not outputting else if?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a small if else statement, where the if gets output, but not the else currently? I tried double pipe, but no luck.

I have a variable set at the top of my page -

```
$portfolio_style = ( isset( $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] ) ? $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] : null );
```

And then my if else which will not work -

```
<?php if ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_one' || 'portfolio_style_two' ) { ?>
    <div class="grid">
<?php } elseif ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_three' ) { ?>
    <div class="wfull">
<?php } ?>
```

I want it where if portfolio style one or two has been selected, show class 'grid', else if style three has been selected show class 'wfull'

Could I also refine this piece of code at all? -

```
 $portfolio_style = ( isset( $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] ) ? $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] : null );
```

Many thanks

Comment: $portfolio_style = ( isset( $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] ) ? $uno_theme['portfolio-style-select'] : null );

Is this code (so errors don't get thrown), refined, or could I improve this also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot omit `$portfolio_style` variable after `||` because otherwise the sole string `'portfolio_style_two'` will always evaluate as `true` as stated in the manual describing [conversion to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

Your code should be this:

```
<?php if ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_one' || $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_two' ) { ?>
    <div class="grid">
<?php } elseif ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_three' ) { ?>
    <div class="wfull">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the if condition:

```
<?php if ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_one' || $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_two' ) { ?>
```

Comment: Is there a more DRY way of doing what you have even suggested? I'm just wanting to learn how to refine things as I go along?

Comment: If you will use any of logical operator than it must be used the comparison variable on both side. this is actually syntax, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line as

```
if ( $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_one' || $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_two' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo ($portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_one' || $portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_two') ? '<div class="grid">'  : (($portfolio_style == 'portfolio_style_three' ) ? '<div class="wfull">' : '');
```